# Download 12.04 onto bootable usb

Tags: installation, usb

I follow the instructions, "How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows".  I have downloaded pendrivelinux.com.  I select the distribution I wish to put on to my USB, which is ubuntu.  Step two, "Browse to your ubuntu *desktop*.iso-->".  I have already opened "Do you want to open or save ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso(708MB) from mirrorsfwankie.com".  When I browse from pendrive USB installer, nothing comes up; a temporary file location is shown in the address bar.  Then I go to computer, and there I find "HD DVD-ROM Drive (F):  Install Ubuntu"  I just do not know what to do from here.  I would appreciate any help with this.  Thank  you.

Comment: Were you able to successfully create a bootable pen drive using the software? When downloading the .iso, you should *save* it, not *open* it, and then browse to the file using whatever application you are using to create the Live USB.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the next step would be to (back up your data) and then boot from the USB thumb drive to try/install Ubuntu. Reboot, and your PC should do this automatically.

- If it does not, you need to go into your BIOS or Setup options on boot and configure the boot order so that the USB drive is on the top of the list.
- If you have a new computer with Windows 8 and UEFI, see [the UEFI documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) if your PC doesn't boot from Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly.  So, when I restart my computer, F12, I select the option to reboot from the E drive.  I get a message, "Remove disks or other media/ Press any key to restart"  I have no disk in the disk drive.  When I look into the E drive, a window opens and shows an ubuntu file folder.  Inside this I have "disks, install and winboot files, an ubuntu icon and an uninstall wubi application.  There are a few empty sub files in each file.

Comment: I was trying to open it.  That was it.  I thank you now via the ubuntu operating system! I take the first steps.  Thanks very much.